# JUJU ERROR machine is already provisioned

Tags: juju

I've destroyed a machine on JUJU Gui and now I'd like re-adding it to the same JUJU model using the command

```
juju add-machine ssh:ubuntu@10.20.81.96 --model vnodeslab
```

but I received that error

*ERROR machine is already provisioned*

I don't want destroy all model and remake all the steps already made on MAAS and JUJU.

Is there a way to avoid that and re-adding the node on JUJU?

Comment: can you share the output of $ juju models? and $ juju status?

Comment: machine is already provisioned however it is not on the list of machines by juju list-machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to cleanup the machine manually before being able to add it again. I am assuming it was no longer in use before you removed it from the gui.

I would try:

```
sudo apt-get remove juju*
```

And if not enough, I would try cleaning unused directories and files (those in my case):

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/jujud*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/juju
sudo rm /usr/bin/juju-run
```

Comment: I had to have re-build all juju environment

Comment: This shouldn't be an accepted answer. Imagine you have to run a productive environment with hundreds or even more machines. And just due to an issue in the deployment tool you have to rebuild the whole environment

Answer (score 0):

SSH to the provisioned machine and run:

```
sudo /sbin/remove-juju-services
```

**Sample output:**

```
removing juju service: /etc/systemd/system/jujud-machine-1-exec-start.sh
Failed to stop jujud-machine-1-exec-start.sh.service: Unit jujud-machine-1-exec-start.sh.service not loaded.
Failed to disable unit: Unit file jujud-machine-1-exec-start.sh.service does not exist.
removing juju service: /etc/systemd/system/jujud-machine-1.service
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/jujud-machine-1.service.
removing /var/lib/juju/db/*
removing /var/lib/juju/raft/*
removing /var/run/juju/*
```